# CSS in newsetter for PC and smartphone

Tags: html, css, newsletter

I am coding  HTML newsletter, I have to code one file that once sent it detects device if it's  smartphone or PC. If PC it shows `600px` width and for smartphones it shows `300px` width.

So how should I set the width property so that it looks as per the width mentioned above.

Comment: A newsletter is typically sent via email. Email does not have the ability to detect devices.

Comment: so if i  add width in % that is also not good , if i set width to 600px  , will it adjust  in   phones ?

Comment: It depends on your layout. If the layout is complex and depends on a 600px width, phone users will just have to zoom/scroll.

Comment: @Diodeus  Layout is very simple , But this is what i am asked to do "The 600px will be the normal view. When the css detects a smartphone or small device, the 300px style should
be used.
"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for [CSS Media Queries](https://www.google.com/search?q=CSS%20Media%20Queries), here is a basic solution that may suit your needs:

```
/* ALL (Fallback), this will be used by browsers that don't support CSS Media Queries  */ 
#container{width:300px;}

/* Screen more than 600px in width */
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px){
    #container{width:600px;}
}

/* Screen less than 600px in width */
@media only screen and (max-width: 599px) {
    #container{width:300px;}
}
```

More examples here: https://github.com/dhgamache/Skeleton/blob/master/stylesheets/skeleton.css#L79

Comment: Why not? Can you cite a reference? I think it would depend on what program/browser is displaying the email. If it's able to display HTML email and pull in a style sheet to being with - why arbitrarily rule out media queries?

Comment: This is what i am asked to do "The 600px will be the normal view. When the css detects a smartphone or small device, the 300px style should
be used.
" so will it work  ? as email does not work with  these tactics

Comment: Why not? Some clients remove the html and body tags so it's always a good idea to wrap your message inside a div (<div id="container">). If the browser doesn't support Media Queries it will use CSS the fallback property I put first on the code.

Comment: Doing a quick google search, I found that some email readers do support media queries, but it's hit or miss. You are not likely to get consistent results for every user. So "Yes" it is possible, but I wouldn't rely on it. There is no guarantee it will work for every user. Maybe an acceptable approach would be to use the media queries, and then also include a link at the top of the email that says "Trouble viewing this email on a mobile device? Click here." The link would take you to a web-page version of your newsletter, where you're media queries are sure to work.

Comment: @NabilKadimi  Thank u very much for your guidance , Just one more thing can i use it without div  inside tables (inline )  . I  prefer to avoid Divs in emai .

Comment: http://www.emailonacid.com/blog/details/C13/media_queries_in_html_emails

Here is the link I found when googling.

Comment: @Sikander Nawaz - Feel free to use <table id="container">

Comment: @Diodeus Media Queries work in email, they just cant be inlined, so they won't work in Gmail. Media Queries are quite a common practice usually referred to 'Responsive Email Design'.

Comment: @NabilKadimi An alternative method is to go with a fluid design that will render at 100% of any device. here is a [fluid example](http://woothemes.createsend1.com/t/ViewEmail/y/1D01C6AE9D028347)

Comment: @John He asked for 300px and 600px! Anyways, width:auto; is the default and it sets the width to 100% of the parent element width.

Comment: @NabilKadimi Sorry meant to @ the original question asker. He might find the alternative method helpful as you can set max-width to 600 on fluid layouts also. The min width would be the device width however, this info may be useful to him or someone else looking for a similar solution

Answer (score 0):

It is very bad practice to use width % because if there are images within the page these will not be effected by this in most browsers. There is no proper way to code an EDM for both mobile devices and computers yet. Email clients and web services are just not up to par for this.

In my opinion, if you want to make it user friendly for both devices then you should be creating content fields similar to that if the windows 8 interface so that it will still look good on the computer and will have a decent look on a mobile device.

So lets take a look at what mobile devices support Media Queries. It is a HUGE hit and miss in this area.

**Supported:**
Android Mail (very buggy), Iphone mail and Ipad mail (>=320px  <= 480px).

This does come with the risk of not having many elements displaying correctly still because it is relatively new still.

**Not Supported**
Android Gmail, Iphone Gmail, Ipad Gmail and Blackberry 8000

The only real option to go with for EDM's is to keep them static meaning you should never try and make it fluid. EDM's basically have a set amount of info in them and images then get sent so there is no need for the widths/heights to be fluid. Doing this only runs the rist of something breaking in another browser or email client.

Comment: " should be creating content fields similar to that if the windows 8 interface so that it will still look good on the computer and will have a decent look on a mobile device."                  Please explain this